# iOS Tumblr Compose View

Tags: ios, uitextview

How can I achieve the following look where they have a title then the divider line and an area to input a body. It appears as though it's almost one UITextView

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple, they use two fields. The first one is a UITextfield, allowing you to use the grey placeholder text that will be removed when the user starts typing. Then add a simple image of a line, and finally a UITextView, allowing you to have multiple lines of body text.

**EDIT:** To remove the rounded border from the text field, in code use:

```
[myTextField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];
```

Or in the attributes inspector in Interface Builder:

[image]

Here's a more detailed, but basic explanation:

```
UITextField *myTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, self.view.bounds.size.width, 44.0f)];
[myTextField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];
[myTextField setPlaceholder:@"Title (optional)"];
[self.view addSubview:myTextField];

UIView *blackLineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, myTextField.frame.origin.y + myTextField.frame.size.height, self.view.bounds.size.width, 3.0f)];
[blackLineView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0f alpha:0.4f]];
[self.view addSubview:blackLineView];

UITextView *myTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, blackLineView.frame.origin.y + blackLineView.frame.size.height, self.view.bounds.size.width, 200.0f)];
[self.view addSubview:myTextView];
```

Comment: but a UITextField has like rounded corners to it and all

Comment: Change the borderStyle of the UITextField to UITextBorderStyleNone and it will remove the border.

Comment: @user577732 In interface builder text fields have these rounded borders enabled by default. See my edit.

Comment: ha well now i feel a bit stupid must have overlooked that thanks!